# Oracle CASE expression confusion

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone tell me what is the wrong in the below query?

```
select case 
         when ANALYSISCODE is null and
              studydomainmdata.studydomainmetadataid > 0
           then 'CD'  
         when ANALYSISCODE is null and
              studydomainmdata.studydomainmetadataid < 0
           then 'CD1'  
         when analysiscode is not null
           then ANALYSISCODE
         else 'N/A'
       end as ANALYSISCODE
from studyanalysis
inner join (slmetadata
              inner join studydomainmdata 
                on slmetadata.slmetadataid = studydomainmdata.slmetadataid and
                   studydomainmdata.studydomainmetadataid=-9)
  on studyanalysis.analysisid = slmetadata.analysisid;
```

My expected result would be:

- CD1 if studydomainmetadataid is less than 0
- CD if studydomainmetadataid > 0 (i,e 85)
- 'xxx' if ANALYSISCODE is not null

I am getting null ANALYSISCODE.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use a more descriptive title the next time and use the `{ }` button to format your code.

Comment: And show any errors you're getting; and if you get the wrong results rather than an error, table structures, sample data and expected output.

Comment: If ANALYSISCODE is null and studydomainmdata.studydomainmetadataid = 0  your query will return null

Comment: @TonyAndrews - won't it go into the `else` in that scenario?

Comment: @Alex, yes, in which case the ANALYSISCODE is returned - which is null!

Comment: @TonyAndrews - I'm confused; why won't it get `'N/A'`? I don't see how that can give `null` at all. I was wondering if there's a `analysiscode` that is blanks, rather than `null`, but I seem to be missing something. Possibly coffee.

Comment: @Alex, no it is me that needs the coffee, you are quite correct!

Comment: @TonyAndrews - Don't feel bad, I read it that way too.

Comment: @user1562787, are you sure your query is actually returning any value at all? If you select `'X'` rather than your case do you get `X` or `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your query is not returning anything at all hence the `CASE` is not being tested and you are not getting any result returned (not even your `ELSE` default value).

To test this guess, wrap you query with a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM` like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM 
(
select case           
       when ANALYSISCODE is null and studydomainmdata.studydomainmetadataid > 0
       then 'CD'
       when ANALYSISCODE is null and studydomainmdata.studydomainmetadataid < 0
       then 'CD1'
       when analysiscode is not null
       then ANALYSISCODE
       else 'N/A'
       end as ANALYSISCODE 
  from studyanalysis 
 inner join (slmetadata 
             inner join studydomainmdata 
                     on slmetadata.slmetadataid = studydomainmdata.slmetadataid 
                    and studydomainmdata.studydomainmetadataid=-9)
    on studyanalysis.analysisid = slmetadata.analysisid
)
```

If the `count(*)` returns `0` then my guess was correct and your query isn't returning any data at all, hence the null value.

The `CASE` statement can only work on records returned by the query, if there are no records retuned the `CASE` is not executed.

Hope it helps...